# Trying to use an EventEmitter and useState at the same time. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs, eventemitter

I'm a bit new to ReactJS and still trying to wrap my head around things. I'm currently having problems using an EventEmitter when also using a useState at the same time.

Here is my sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-germain-q4933

If you watch the console and click on either the "emit" or "child emit" buttons, it works fine.  The signal is being emitted and received.  However, as soon as you click the "child count" button a few times, and then go back and click the "child emit", you will see things starting to repeat.

This problem seems to only happen when you use a useState and emitter.on in the same child.  It probably has do with passing an emitter as a prop.  Not sure if that is a good idea or not.

What am I missing conceptually here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not define your emitter instances directly within the function render cycle. Instead you must create and add listner events only once.

To create a listner just once, use useRef and to add a listner just once, use useEffect hook

Sample code

```
const App = props => {
  const myEmitter = useRef(new EventEmitter());
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    myEmitter.current.on("event", msg => {
      console.log("Parent received: " + msg);
    });
  }, []);

  const Send = () => {
    myEmitter.current.emit("event", "parent sending this message.");
  };

  return (
    <Content>
      <button onClick={Send}>emit</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>count {counter}</button>
      <Child myEmitter={myEmitter.current} />
    </Content>
  );
};
```

---

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Child = props => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    props.myEmitter.on("event", msg => {
      console.log("Child received: " + msg);
    });
  }, [props.myEmitter]);

  const Emit = () => {
    props.myEmitter.emit("event", "child sending this message");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={Emit}>child emit</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>
        child count {counter}
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

[**Demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-http-9gyk3)